# How can I store a value in session state using nextjs with new app directory?

Tags: reactjs, next.js13

I am building a nextjs 13 app using the new app folder. Users can log into other systems, then link into my new app, passing their refresh token in the header or url. I then use the refresh token to get an access token and store both tokens against a new GUID in an in-memory cache **server-side**. I need to be able to retrieve the correct tokens to use for the API calls **per user**. All of this can happen in memory, I do not need to persist the data beyond the length of the session.

The purpose of this is to protect the tokens, so that only the GUID should be passed back and forth to the client. The tokens should only exist server-side, for use in API requests only.

I am looking at using next-auth and its getServerSession method. I am also looking at using middleware, but the documentation says TODO (https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/middleware). I still can't seem to find a simple session storage for use server-side.

Is it possible to store a value in a per-user session that is accessible server-side to distinguish between users? Or do I need to revert back to the pages directory to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had some luck following this blog post and using the `cache` function to make data available across all server components for the lifetime of a query: https://prismic.io/blog/advanced-nextjs-server-context

However I still struggled with passing tokens back and forth to the client. I've decided to revert back to the stable pages directory structure for my nextjs app and use the next-auth package instead.